# Pycharm setting question. (Sorry, I'm a newbie.)

Tags: python, colors, pycharm

I have some questions.

1) In my `Pycharm`, I am using `Darcula` as a background of `Pycharm`.
I want to add color to sentence such as

```
Ex)
print("-----")
```

This is what I want to change. 
I want to change the color of the letter `"print"` to orange. 
Also, I want to change the color of `("------")` as light green.

Another question. 
When I type any types of functions, I want to see the description of it. 
right now, all the letters are blue-ish color. 
It is so hard to read.

Comment: `Settings > Editor > Color Scheme > Python` and you can set every single color of everything

Comment: Thank you so much!! I'm going to look into it!!